# Confused with estimator for random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution, order-statistics

I am working on a practice exercise in preparation for a final this week. I am really stuck on the following problem:

Let $X_1, X_2$ be a random sample for a population with the probability density function
$$ f_k(x) = 
\left\{ \begin{matrix}
{\displaystyle \frac{6x(k-x)}{k^3}} & \textrm{ if } 0 \leq x \leq k \\ 
\qquad 0            & \textrm{ else }  
\end{matrix} \right. $$
where $k>0$. Let $\hat{X} = X_1 + X_2$. Using $\hat{X}$ as an estimator, find the 90% confidence interval for $k$.

I am mostly looking for a place to start on the problem. I am not sure how to utilize what I know about estimators.

Comment: One thing to notice is that $E[X]=k$

Comment: I am not really sure how that helps. Are you referring to the fact that $bias = E[\hat{X}] - X$ ?

Comment: When I went through and did the expected value of the population I actually got $\frac{k}{2} = E[X]$

Comment: "Using $\hat{X}$ as an estimator" As an estimator of what? It seems to me (pardon if I'm mistaken) that you have some conceptual problem here, as shown by your wrong definition of the bias . An estimator (in this context) estimates a _parameter_ of the density function. You seem to believe that the estimator estimates $X$. It does not. It estimates (in this case) $k$

Answer (score 0):

Define $Y_i=X_i/k,\quad i=1,2$. Then $Y_i \overset{iid}{\sim} Beta(2,2)$, hence $\hat{X}/k=Y_1+Y_2$ is your pivotal quantity (random variable free from k). So do this:

1. Find the distribution of $Z=Y_1+Y_2,$ the sum of two iid $Beta(2,2)$ random variables
2. Find positive constants $a,b$ (may not be unique) such that $P(a<Z<b)=.90$
3. Since $Z=\hat{X}/k$, the 90% CI is $(\hat{X}/b,\hat{X}/a)$

Hope this helps!